# Lie Algebra of Aut(GL(n,R))

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, automorphism-groups, crossed-modules

What is the Lie Algebra of $Aut(Gl(n,F))$ when $F$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Is it enough to consider the injection via [Hochschild](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1952-072-02/S0002-9947-1952-0045735-2/S0002-9947-1952-0045735-2.pdf):
$Aut(GL(n)) \to Aut(\mathfrak{gl}(n))$?

Edit: The issue is, if I consider $der(\mathfrak{gl}(n))$ then I know I have elements in $Aut(GL(n))$ of the form $(M \to BMB^{-1})$ and $(M \to |det(M)|^cM)$ from some $c \ne -\frac{1}{n}$.  I could then find elements of the form $(M \to [B,M])$ and $(M \to c\cdot tr(M)M)$ in $der(\mathfrak{gl}(n))$.

What I don't know is why (if I can) think of those elements as sitting in $Aut(GL(n))$.

Comment: As far as I know, the connected component of the identity is just $PGL_n$ in both cases. (I assume that in the complex case you mean holomorphic automorphisms.)

Comment: In the complex case, I meant either holomorphic automorphisms or, considering $Aut(GL(n))$ in terms of thinking of everything still as a real vector space.

Comment: I also don't understand how the connected component of $I$ in $GL(n)$ is $PGL_n$, since in the projective group, you have quotiented by the center, but there are still commuting elements in $GL(n)$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I mean the connected component of the identity of the automorphism group.

Comment: Do you have a reference or an argument?

Comment: Beware that if $n$ is odd $GL(n,\mathbf{R})\simeq SL(n,\mathbf{R})\times\mathbf{R}$, so the automorphism group is isomorphic to $PGL_n(\mathbf{R})\times\mathbf{R}^*$, in contradiction with some claims.

Comment: In the complex case the answer depends on whether you consider the automorphism group as real or complex Lie group.

Comment: You start by asking for the derivations of the Lie algebra. You remember (Knapp, Lie Groups Beyond p.102) that the derivations of a semisimple Lie algebra are inner. So you see what the derivations of sl(n) are. Then I think it is not too tricky.

Comment: Are you first claiming that the Lie Algebra of $Aut(GL(n))$ is semisimple?  Or are you saying that I can relate $aut(GL(n))$ to $der(gl(n))$?

Comment: And I understand the answer depends on whether I consider the automorphism group as real or complex, see my comment above where I said I am interesting in all cases: "I mean either... or".

Comment: @BenMcKay I edited my question to try and point to where my question really lies.

Comment: If $G$ is a connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and universal covering $\tilde{G}$, so that $G=\tilde{G}/Z$ with $Z$ discrete and central, then $\mathrm{Aut}(\tilde{G})=\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ (this is a Lie group with finitely many components and Lie algebra $\mathrm{Der}(\mathfrak{g})$), and $\mathrm{Aut}(G)=\{u\in\mathrm{Aut}(\tilde{G}):u(Z)=Z\}$ (this is a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(\tilde{G})$, possibly of positive codimension). In the present case all verifications are routine exercise and this is not a research-level question.

Comment: @YCor I think you have helped me answer my question, albeit cryptically and condescendingly, so thanks, I guess.

Comment: In particular, $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is not a connected Lie Group.  If you want to consider its connected component, it isn't clear how to translate that into the components of the automorphism group.